# jquery Slidedown making queue

Tags: jquery, queue, slidedown

I am sliding down some content when a user mouse over on it and sliding up on mouse out. My problem is when I move mouse frequently until it's slideup or slidedown it doesn't show. Means it's creating a queue.

```
$(function(){
    $('div[tooltip="true"]').hover(
        function(e){
            x = e.clientX;
            y = e.clientY;
            newX = x + 10;
            newY = y + 5;
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').css({'left':newX, 'top':newY});
            html_content = '<p>Some Html content</p>';
            $('div#tool_tip_text_content').html(html_content);
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').slideDown(500);
        },
        function(e){
            $('div#tool_tip_text_content').html('');
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').slideUp(0);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of [jQuery.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the current queue in action. Your code should look like:

```
$(function(){
    $('div[tooltip="true"]').hover(
        function(e){
            x = e.clientX;
            y = e.clientY;
            newX = x + 10;
            newY = y + 5;
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').css({'left':newX, 'top':newY});
            html_content = '<p>Some Html content</p>';
            $('div#tool_tip_text_content').html(html_content);
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
        },
        function(e){
            $('div#tool_tip_text_content').html('');
            $('#tool_tip_text_content').stop(true,true).slideUp(0);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: if I only use stop it doesn't work. But if I use stop(true, true) than it works.

Comment: As stated on the docs, .stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] ), you can use the two variables for many purposes.

Comment: thanks you made the base from where I jump into the solution. Many many thanks.